# contain overflowing element

Tags: html, css

I am using a library in react (react-dimensions) that wraps my elements in a div with `height:0; width: 0; overflow: visible`

This breaks my styles.

I was wondering if there is a way for the parent to contain the overflowing child.

I have prepared a demo:

```css
.parent {
  /* ??? */
}

.child {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      This box overflows!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Other content...
</p>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/egEBev

Comment: What do you mean by 'contain'? you don't want it to overlap?

Comment: What styles is it breaking too?

Comment: I want them to stack properly

Answer (score 2):

I admit that I found this by trying, but it kind of works when you make the parent an `inline-block` - see snippet and codepen. At least it moves the subsequent content down without overlapping.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxjxRv

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.child {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      This box overflows!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Other content...
</p>
```

Comment: Ended up forking the library and fixing the problem from the source... but thank you anyway

Comment: Also the solution only works for text. it doesn't actually contain the element, it only contains the text. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ndvdew

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `overflow:hidden` on a parent to hide children that overflow. But it looks like there might be another problem with how you're using `react-dimensions`... I'm not sure specifically how that library works.

Comment: I think that's a weird choice for the library to have 0 0 wrapper, but the maintainer is saying that this is an "attempt to make it 'invisible' to layout". But I am feeling the opposite. https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions/issues/35#issuecomment-244230997

Comment: Also I don't want to hide the content, I want them to stack up normally